# Landscape IOS app throws exception when presenting modal viewController

Tags: ios, landscape, presentviewcontroller

for reference, I am using Xcode 6.1 and targeting IOS 7.1.
Looks like there are posts with similar problems but the suggestions have not worked for me. 
I have an app which I designed to work only in landscape mode. So I set the project to support only Landscape Right and Landscape Left orientation.
But when in my code I want to present a new viewController, the app throws an exception and crashes at the "presentViewController" statement in the code below:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    PhotoViewController *photoVC = [storyboard
                                  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoViewController"];
    // Configure the new view controller here.

    //photoVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

    photoVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,568, 320);

    [self presentViewController:photoVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

By the way for testing purposes I hardwired 568 and 320 for the width and height.

The error message says:

> uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Autolayout >doesn't support crossing rotational bounds transforms with edge layout >constraints, such as right, left, top, bottom. The offending view is: 
>   UITransitionView: 0x1701fa700; frame = (-2.84217e-14 0; 320 568); transform =
>   [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0];

One thing I do not understand is why the "frame" in the error message shows 320 as width and 568 as height, when the "presentViewController" is passing a viewController with the frame set in landscape mode (width=568, height=320) . 
The error message also complains about "crossing rotational bounds transforms", which sort of hints that the viewController's view is being rotated?

any idea what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: Is your `PhotoViewController` actually set up to only allow landscape orientations, or are you relying strictly on setting the frame to do that for you (hint: it won't)?

Comment: According to the ViewController Programming Guide when you specify at the application level that your application supports particular orientations , this choice applies to all viewControllers in the app.  It says:    "If you restrict the app’s supported orientations, then those restrictions apply globally to all of the app’s view controllers,"     But I also included the "supportedInterfaceOrientations" in the PhotoViewController to specify the that it supports landscape Right and Left, but the error is still the same

Comment: Have you tried not explicitly setting the frame and letting the system do that for you?

Comment: Yes, still I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, I found out that setting the "setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" to NO was causing the problem.  I used it in viewDidLoad of the presenting ViewController:

```
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

So I removed this statement.
I used this statement to make sure I wouldn't have constraints conflicts between Interface Builders creation of automatic layout constraints and the auto layout constraints I added programmatically. 
So when I removed the statement I of course got constraints conflicts, but I eliminated them by "removing" existing constraints in viewDidLoad for every subview for which there were constraints conflicts. 
By the way,  my programmatic constraints are called in "updateViewConstraints"

I do not completely understand why setting the setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO was causing the problem of not being able to present a new viewController modally, but my guess is that setting "setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" to YES is somehow needed for the system to figure out automatically the orientation and size of the presenting viewController.